# Label at the bottom disappears on increasing font size of text editor

Tags: tkinter, text-editor

I am making a text editor in tkinter. I noticed that when I increase the font size to more than 16, the status bar(Label at the bottom) disappears on its own and reappear when I decrease size less than 17.
Below is the minimum workable example of my code.
I think it is because the text editor takes more space upon increase in font size but still it shouldn't  take remove the status bar under any circumstance.
Are their any fixes or its just how it is ?

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.font import Font

main_application = tk.Tk()

#################################### MAIN-MENU ###########################################
main_menu = tk.Menu()

File = tk.Menu(main_menu,tearoff=False)
main_menu.add_cascade(label='File',menu=File)


# #################################### TOOLBAR ###########################################
tool_bar = ttk.Label(main_application)
tool_bar.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X)


##font size box
size_var = tk.IntVar()
font_size = ttk.Combobox(tool_bar, width=14,textvariable=size_var,state='readonly',cursor='hand2')
font_size['values'] = tuple(range(8,81,1))
font_size.current(2)
font_size.grid(row=0,column=6,padx=2)


#################################### TEXT-EDITOR ##########################################
text_editor = tk.Text(main_application)
text_editor.config(wrap='word',relief=tk.FLAT, undo=True)
text_editor.focus_set()

yscroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(main_application)
yscroll_bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)

text_editor.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
yscroll_bar.config(command=text_editor.yview)
text_editor.config(yscrollcommand=yscroll_bar.set)


#################################### STATUS BAR ##########################################
status_bar = ttk.Label(main_application,compound=tk.LEFT)
status_bar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.X)



#################################### MAIN-MENU FUNCTIONALITY ###########################################

## font family and font size functionality
my_font=Font(family='Arial',size=12)      
text_editor.configure(font=my_font)

## states of the formatting buttons
current_font_size = 12


def change_font_size(event=None):
    global current_font_size
    current_font_size = size_var.get()
    change_formatting()
font_size.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",change_font_size)


## to change formatting
def change_formatting():
    my_font.configure(size=current_font_size )



################################################## runner code ################################33333
main_application.state('zoomed')
main_application.config(menu=main_menu)
main_application.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the font size, it's going to cause the text widget to grow since the height is given in the number of lines and the font size changes the line height.

When when `pack` actually adds widgets to the window, it will stop adding widgets once the window cannot grow any more and it's not able to shrink the current widgets based on their options and requested size. So, as the text widget grows and grows, eventually it fills the window. Once the window is full, `pack` stops adding widgets to the window.

This is what the canonical tcl/tk documentation on the packing algorithm has to say (with emphasis added by me):

> If the cavity should become too small to meet the needs of a slave then the slave will be given whatever space is left in the cavity. *If the cavity shrinks to zero size, then all remaining slaves on the packing list will be unmapped from the screen* until the master window becomes large enough to hold them again.

In other words, it gives priority to widget packed earlier over widgets packed later.

A simple fix is to pack the statusbar before packing the text widget. That way the statusbar will already be on the screen, so when you add the text widget `pack` will shrink it in order for it to fit.

This is a good reason why putting all of the `pack` commands for a group of children together rather than sprinkling them throughout the code makes sense. You can create the widgets in the order you think makes sense, but then pack them in the order required by the behavior you want.

If you move all of your calls to `pack` in a group organized by parent widget (ie: all children of `main_application` are packed together), it would look like the following. By placing `text_editor` last, this ensures that all of the other widgets are visible before the window fills up and that `pack` will start shrinking the requested size of the text widget when there is no room.

```
tool_bar.pack(side=tk.TOP,fill=tk.X)
status_bar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM,fill=tk.X)
yscroll_bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,fill=tk.Y)
text_editor.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I also wanted to ask whether `grid` also behaves same as `pack` in this?